# How can I change the disk that lando use for the database

Tags: wordpress, lando

So I got a lando recipe for wordpress. I have two disk. One is my main disk that is almost full (and SSD that only have like 2GB of empty space) and the other one is an external drive that have plenty of space, like 1.5TB.

This is my lando recipe

```
name: my_case_project
```

recipe: wordpress
config:
php: '7.4'
via: nginx
database: mariadb
webroot: web
xdebug: false

services:
pma:
type: phpmyadmin
hosts:
- database

database:
type: mariadb
overrides:
volumes:
- /media/jose/nuevovol/landodatabases:/var/lib/mysql

tooling:
xdebug-toggle:
service: appserver
description: Toggle Xdebug on or off
cmd: if grep -q 'xdebug.mode=off' /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/docker-php-ext-xdebug.ini; then sed -i 's/xdebug.mode=off/xdebug.mode=debug/g' /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/docker-php-ext-xdebug.ini && echo 'Xdebug enabled'; else sed -i 's/xdebug.mode=debug/xdebug.mode=off/g' /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/docker-php-ext-xdebug.ini && echo 'Xdebug disabled'; fi
user: root

Where /media/jose/nuevovol/landodatabases is a new disk  When I run lando start and start pushing my db backup on to mariadb, it just use the space of the main disk instead of the space on the other disk.

What would I need to change to make this happens?